# spark textInput in Flex 4.12.1 and 4.13 issue

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

When a spark textInput is used with displayAsPassword=true in Apache Flex 4.12.1 and 4.13 throws "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flashx.textLayout.factory:TextLineFactoryBase::_pass0Lines is not defined."

Works well if either spark textInput is replaced with mx textInput or Flex 4.12 and earlier.

Thanks

Comment: Why the odd version numbers? Is there a specific reason you are not using a stable release?

Comment: Both 4.12.1 and 4.13 are stable releases. 4.13 being the latest stable release.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I didn't realize apache restarted the version numbers. I am still working on the 4.6.0 release from Adobe.

Comment: Maybe it is better to submit a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX/